# How to replace ABC with ABCD but not ABCD with ABCDD

Tags: replace

I have some large text files were I need to do some text replacements with replace all.

However the replaced text contains the original text which creates a infinite loop.

I need some method or a program that do a replace-all and check if the replacement was already done. Something to check if the found match for ABC is already part of ABCD and skip that replacement.

The ABC from my example is just a basic case and can be any sequence of characters so using an option like match whole sting only does not work.

Comment: In what computer language?

Comment: Plain text ? (Notepad) I am not looking to develop it, just looking to make the change in existing text/code. Is there a better forum for this question? Thanks.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. I don't know of a better site for this... Maybe [su]? You should read the [help center](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) of their site first before asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a language or tool that supports **regular expressions**, and use **look-ahead**.

As a trivial example in a bash shell:

```
echo "ABCEE" | grep -P -o "ABC(?=[^D])"
```

outputs "ABC" (i.e., it finds a match)

where:

```
echo "ABCDE" | grep -P -o "ABC(?=[^D])"
```

does not -- it does not match.

The (?=...) means "followed by" and "[^D]" means "by anything other than D".

You can get more sophisticated using **capture groups** which would capture "ABC" -- look into regular expressions and you should find plenty of options.

Comment: Specifically, `[^D]` means "a single character that is not D", so your expression won't match `ABC` by itself.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I guess if you are talking about lines of text, you could use "ABC(?=([^D]|^))". LOL for the downvote.

Comment: ... or you could just use `ABC(?!D)`.

Comment: Thanks, that works great. Seems many programs and IEDs support regex (EditPad lite, Notepadd++) it is just a question of turning it on. Makes things much easier. Thanks again.